# Aligning nested polynomial

Tags: math-mode, align, mathjax, alignat

The following MathJax is used in [my code golf answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269079/17360). How can I neatly align the terms while getting the main idea across? Maybe the fractions and the integers both need to be aligned? Any other TeX tips are appreciated.

[image: align preview]

```
\begin{alignat}{1}
e &\approx 2 + \phantom{} && \biggl[  &\frac 1 2 \biggl(1 + \phantom{} &&\frac 1 3 \biggl( 1 + \phantom{} &\frac 1 4 (1) \biggr)  \biggr) \biggr]  \\
&= 2 + \frac{1}{10} && \biggl[  &\frac 1 2 \biggl( 10 + \phantom{} &&\frac 1 3 \biggl( 10 + \phantom{} &\frac 1 4 (10) \biggr)  \biggr) \biggr]  \\
&= 2 + \frac{1}{10} && \biggl[  &\frac 1 2 \biggl( 10 + \phantom{} &&\frac 1 3 \biggl( 12 + \phantom{} &\frac 1 4 (2) \biggr)  \biggr) \biggr]  \\
&= 2 + \frac{1}{10} && \biggl[  &\frac 1 2 \biggl( 14 + \phantom{} &&\frac 1 3 \biggl( 0 + \phantom{} &\frac 1 4 (2) \biggr)  \biggr) \biggr]  \\
&= 2 + \frac{1}{10} && \biggl[7 + \phantom{}  &\frac 1 2 \biggl( 0 + \phantom{} &&\frac 1 3 \biggl( 0 + \phantom{} &\frac 1 4 (2) \biggr)  \biggr) \biggr]  \\
\end{alignat}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some `\phantom{0}`s were needed, here denoted as `\pp`.  Also, all `\phantom{}` could be replaced with `{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\pp{\phantom{0}}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{4}
e 
&\approx 2 + {} && \biggl[  &\frac 1 2 \biggl(\pp1 + {} 
  &&\frac 1 3 \biggl(\pp1 + {} &\frac 1 4 (\pp1) \biggr) \biggr) \biggr]\\
&= 2 + \frac{1}{10} && \biggl[  &\frac 1 2 \biggl( 10 + {} 
  &&\frac 1 3 \biggl( 10 + {} &\frac 1 4 (10) \biggr)  \biggr) \biggr]\\
&= 2 + \frac{1}{10} && \biggl[  &\frac 1 2 \biggl( 10 + {} 
  &&\frac 1 3 \biggl( 12 + {} &\frac 1 4 (\pp2) \biggr)  \biggr) \biggr]\\
&= 2 + \frac{1}{10} && \biggl[  &\frac 1 2 \biggl( 14 + {} 
  &&\frac 1 3 \biggl(\pp0 + {} &\frac 1 4 (\pp2) \biggr) \biggr) \biggr]\\
&= 2 + \frac{1}{10} && \biggl[7 + {}  &\frac 1 2 \biggl(\pp0 + {}
  &&\frac 1 3 \biggl(\pp0 + {} &\frac 1 4 (\pp2) \biggr) \biggr) \biggr]
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very good. Do you think it would look better if all the numbers were centered? I don't know if that is possible within alignat.

Comment: @qwr -- In successive lines with very similar structure, alignment of digits according to an assumed decimal point makes the most sense.

Comment: @qwr I concur with Barbara, a noted expert in such matters.